# Música no se reproduce al pararla y carga otro archivo

Tags: python, pygame

El sonido se carga a través de la siguiente función

```
def load_music(path):
    pg.mixer.music.load(BASE_MUS_PATH + path)
    pg.mixer.music.play()
```

En esta primera parte funciona correctamente

```
def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.state == "main_title":
                if pg.mixer.music.get_busy() == False:
                    load_music("main_title.ogg")
```

Sin embargo, cambio el estado y la música deja de sonar, pero no reproduce el nuevo archivo.

```
if self.state == "first_phase":
                pg.mixer.music.stop()
                if pg.mixer.music.get_busy() == False:
                    load_music("first_phase.ogg")
```

Por más vueltas que le doy no consigo ver donde está el problema. He cambiado el formato de los archivos y tampoco funciona, por lo que descarto que no pueda reproducir dicho archivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu condicional se ejecuta dentro del mainloop, ten en cuenta que estas deteniendo la reproducción en cada frame.

```
if self.state == "first_phase":
    pg.mixer.music.stop()       # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Si lo que quieres es reproducir la música de fondo en un loop infinito y que cambie acorde al estado, en vez de hacerlo en el mainloop, deberías simplemente cargar la canción adecuada solo cuando el estado cambie y reproducirla en bucle pasando `-1` como argumento a `pygameg.mixer.music.play()`), en vez de comprobarlo con `get_busy()` en cada frame.

Un ejemplo reproducible basado en los fragmentos de tu código:

```
import pathlib
import sys

import pygame as pg


BASE_MUS_PATH = pathlib.Path("./assets/music")


def load_music(path):
    pg.mixer.music.load(BASE_MUS_PATH.joinpath(path))
    pg.mixer.music.play(-1)


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.display = pg.display.set_mode((600, 400))
        self._state = None

    @property
    def state(self):
        return self._state

    @state.setter
    def state(self, new_state):
        match new_state:
            case self._state:
                return
            case "main_title":
                load_music("main_title.ogg")
            case "first_phase":
                load_music("first_phase.ogg")
            case _:
                raise ValueError("Invalid state")
        self._state = new_state

    def run(self):
        self.state = "main_title"

        while True:
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    pg.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                    match event.key:
                        case pg.K_ESCAPE:
                            self.state = "main_title"
                        case pg.K_RETURN:
                            self.state = "first_phase"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = Game()
    game.run()
```

Para reproducir el ejemplo basta con cambiar la ruta de BASE_MUS_PATH a la del directorio donde se encuentren los dos archivos `main_title.ogg` y `first_phase.ogg`. Al pulsar <kbd>ESC</kbd> se cambia al estado `"main_title"` y al pulsar <kbd>Enter</kbd> a `"first_phase"`, cambiando la música con ello.

---

Nota aparte, la forma correcta (o mas "pythonica") de comprobar si un objeto es o no verdadero no es:

```
if obj == True: / if obj == False:
```

sino:

```
if obj: / if not obj:
```

Es decir, deberías hacer simplemente:

```
if not pg.mixer.music.get_busy():
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: No es pitónico, es bastante común en realidad. Tanto java como typescript (que son los lenguajes que uso a diario, por eso menciono solo esos) usan también el `if (obj)` sin añadir las comprobaciones. Es bastante más limpio :)

Comment: @Benito-B si, es común en otros lenguajes también, de alto nivel especialmente.  No solo es mas legible y escribes menos código, en el caso concreto de Python es mas eficiente, si no recuerdo mal son dos instrucciones menos en el bytecode generado en comparación con usar el operador...